# How to save data from Fb.api to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use the below script to get friend list after acknowledge App.

How can i call a value to save then into mysql table. Any suggestion ?

If i do something like this in order to call it, it is not working:

```
userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' '<div name="savename"> + response.name</div>;
```

Below full script

```
<?php

$sApplicationId = 'YOUR_APPLICATION_ID';
$sApplicationSecret = 'YOUR_APPLICATION_SECRET';
$iLimit = 99;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Facebook API - Get friends list</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <img src="facebook.png" class="facebook" alt="facebook" />

        <center>
            <h1>Authorization step:</h1>
            <div id="user-info"></div>
            <button id="fb-auth">Please login here</button>
        </center>

        <div id="result_friends"></div>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>

        <script>
        function sortMethod(a, b) {
            var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
            var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({ appId: '<?= $sApplicationId ?>',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true
            });

            function updateButton(response) {
                var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

                if (response.authResponse) { // in case if we are logged in
                    var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
                        button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
                    });

                    // get friends
                    FB.api('/me/friends?limit=<?= $iLimit ?>', function(response) {
                        var result_holder = document.getElementById('result_friends');
                        var friend_data = response.data.sort(sortMethod);

                        var results = '';
                        for (var i = 0; i < friend_data.length; i++) {
                            results += '<div><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id + '/picture">' + friend_data[i].name + '</div>';
                        }

                        // and display them at our holder element
                        result_holder.innerHTML = '<h2>Result list of your friends:</h2>' + results;
                    });

                    button.onclick = function() {
                        FB.logout(function(response) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        });
                    };
                } else { // otherwise - dispay login button
                    button.onclick = function() {
                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        }, {scope:'email'});
                    }
                }
            }

            // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
            FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
        };

        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the things up. You use JavaScript to get the friends via the Facebook JavaScript API. To save them into a MySQL database you need a server-side language like PHP (the one which you use at the top). So, I'll suggest to wrap your data into a JSON object and it to a PHP script which will put the information into a database.

Comment: Hi again, i am having some problems and not sure how to do this since i haven't worked before with JSON. Can you please assist me with the script ?

Comment: Download and include this file into your page https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js
After that just use JSON.stringify(response) to convert the object returned by the API to a string. Actually if you use a library like jQuery you don't need to convert anything to JSON or a string. You could send directly the response.